# Alguien sabe por qué se duplican los $_POST con JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post

Tengo un problema, lo que pasa es que con Ajax estoy insertando registros en una base de datos de manera asíncrona (sin recargar la página) a través del método $_POST. Todo bien cuando inserto el primer registro, pero cuando quiero insertar otro registro se envía 2 veces, y cada vez que ingreso un nuevo registro este se duplica y así sucesivamente.

He intentado con un 'return false' cuando cierro 'ajax({});', vaciando las variables en el beforeSend, en el success, dentro del if y else, y aún así no me funciona

Código del formulario el cual es un modal:

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="formAddVehiculo" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="modalTittle" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <form id="formCrearVehiculo" method="post">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-tittle" id="modalTittle">Agregar nuevo vehículo</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="mb-1">
                        <input required type="text" class="form-control" name="txtpatente" id="txtpatente" placeholder="Patente del vehículo">
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-1">
                        <input required type="text" class="form-control" name="txtmarca" id="txtmarca" placeholder="Marca del vehículo">
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-1">
                        <input required type="text" class="form-control" name="txtmodelo" id="txtmodelo" placeholder="Modelo del vehículo">
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-1">
                        <input required type="number" min="1886" max="2022" minlength="4" maxlength="4" class="form-control" name="intanio" id="intanio" placeholder="Año del vehículo">
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-1">
                        <input required type="datetime-local" class="form-control" name="datefecha" id="datefecha" placeholder="">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button class="btn btn-success" type="button" id="btnCrearVehiculo">Agregar</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-danger" type="reset">Borrar</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Fin del modal -->
```

Código de la función:

```
$('#btnCrearVehiculo').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var dataVehiculo = '';
    txtpatente = $('#txtpatente').val();
    txtmarca = $('#txtmarca').val();
    txtmodelo = $('#txtmodelo').val();
    intanio = $('#intanio').val();
    datefecha = $('#datefecha').val();
    const action = 'crearVehiculo';

    $.ajax({
        url: './app/ajaxVehiculo.php',
        type: 'POST',
        async: true,
        data: {
            action:action,
            txtpatente:txtpatente,
            txtmarca:txtmarca,
            txtmodelo:txtmodelo,
            intanio:intanio,
            datefecha:datefecha
        },
        beforeSend: function() {
            // Deshabilitamos el botón mientras se ejecuta
            $("#btnCrearVehiculo").html('Espere...').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            const action = '';
        },
        success: function(response){
            // Volvemos a habilitar el botón
            $("#btnCrearVehiculo").html('Agregar').removeAttr('disabled');
            // Vaciamos las variables
            txtpatente = $('#txtpatente').val("");
            txtmarca = $('#txtmarca').val("");
            txtmodelo = $('#txtmodelo').val("");
            intanio = $('#intanio').val("");
            datefecha = $('#datefecha').val("");

            if (response == 'notData') {
                Swal.fire({
                    title: "El vehículo que quiere registrar ya existe",
                    icon: "error"
                });
            }
            else if(response == 'camposVacios')
            {
                console.log(response);
            }
            else {
                $("#rowsVehiculos").load("#rowsVehiculos");
                Swal.fire({
                    title: "Registro exitoso",
                    icon: "success"
                });
            }
        },
        error: function(response){
            console.log('En error: function()');
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Edito la pregunta agregando el código PHP, y arriba en la función agregando la validación else if(response == 'camposVacios')

```
//Arriba de este else if hay otras validaciones
else if( $_POST['action'] == 'crearVehiculo' )
{
    $patente=strtoupper($_POST['txtpatente']);
    $marca=trim($_POST['txtmarca']);
    $modelo=trim($_POST['txtmodelo']);
    $anio=trim($_POST['intanio']);
    $fecharegistro=$_POST['datefecha'];
    if(empty($patente) || empty($marca) || empty($modelo) || empty($anio) || empty($fecharegistro))
    {
        echo 'camposVacios';
    }
    else
    {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM vehiculos WHERE patente = '$patente'";
        $query_select = mysqli_query($conexion,$query);
        if( !empty($query_select) AND mysqli_num_rows($query_select) > 0 )
        {
            echo 'notData';
        }
        else
        {
            $queryinsert = "INSERT INTO vehiculos (patente,marca,modelo,anio_vehiculo,fecha_registro)
                            VALUES ('$patente','$marca','$modelo','$anio','$fecharegistro')";
            try 
            {
                mysqli_query($conexion,$queryinsert);
                echo 'created';
            } catch (Exception $e){
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Por más que edito la pregunta, no me permite anteponer un Hola a todos, así que los saludo por acá :)

Comment: Las preguntas y respuestas no deben llevar saludos ni nada parecido. Deben ser impersonales.  Desconozco porque no te deja ponerlos, pero los que revisamos tenemos la obligación de quitarlos si alguien los ha puesto, así que tranquilo, igualmente no te hubiera durado mucho. Léete [ask] y haz el [tour] para aprender cómo funciona este sitio, gracias.

Comment: A simple vista parece que está todo bien, no se detectar el fallo. ¿Puedes poner la parte de PHP donde haces el INSERT?  Quizás allí está el error.

Comment: asi a primeras, parece que por una parte se hace el ajax correspondiente, y por otra se envia el formulario. es como si tu boton fuera un "submit". Has probado a quitar las etiquetas de <form></form> y dejarlo solo como un modal? aparte: que es el `$("#btnCrearVehiculor")` que tienes en el javascript? (acaba con R) y no lo tienes en ningun otro sitio...

Comment: Es probable que estés asignando el evento dentro de un ciclo o evento, tal vez cada que muestras la modal y por eso se van acumulando.

Comment: Masterguru, acabo de editar la pregunta agregando el código en php.

Comment: Jakala, he probado sin las etiquetas <form> </form> y sigue el mismo error, y respecto a $("#btnCrearVehiculor") se me coló esa r al final y ya lo modifiqué.

Comment: Triby, he intentado cerrando el modal cada vez que inserto un nuevo registro y sigue el mismo error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías revisar al inspeccionar elemento del navegador que el evento click no este ejecutándose dos veces. En la pestaña de red te muestra si la llamada a ajaxVehiculo.php se repitió.
Puedes agregar luego del e.preventDefault(), e.stopImmediatePropagation();

Comment: Muchas gracias nano, de momento si me funciona, sólo que me salta un error con el DataTable(), a la hora de destruir la instancia